# Assigning Style in cs code to a tabitem in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, computer-science

**Hi, I have created a custom style in xaml:**

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TabEnabledEffect" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowBitmapEffect ShadowDepth="10" Color="Orange" Direction="90" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

**And in cs file:**
i have a tabitem with name "tab1" and im trying to assign that style to it on button_click event with the following code:

*`tab1.Style = (Style)FindResource("TabEnabledEffect");`*

**And after running it im getting the exception:**

NullReferenceException
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `Application.Current.FindResource("TabEnabledEffect") as Style;` or `App.Current.FindResource("TabEnabledEffect") as Style;`

Comment: It worked, Thanx! @bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you are in your code. In your code-behind file you can use the line of code you had:

```
tab1.Style = this.FindeResource("TabEnabledEffect") as Style;
```

When you are in an other file you have to use the statement mentioned by @bit:

```
tab1.Style = Application.Current.FindResource("TabEnabledEffect") as Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use

```
Application.Current.FindResource("TabEnabledEffect") as Style;
```

since you have declared the resource at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign style by writing below code after loading the `InitializeComponent()` method

```
control_name.style=this.FindResource("style_name")
```